# react render twice with hooks when i setCount in setInterval?

Tags: react-hooks

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(60);
    console.log("useEffect before", count);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect", count);
        const timeId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("count", count);
            setCount(59);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {};
    }, []);
    console.log("useEffect after", count);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>{count}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Why was 59 executed twice？
i think it should be once，but it is not,why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdoFf.png)

Comment: useEffect before 60
 useEffect after 60
useEffect 60
count 60
useEffect before 59
useEffect after 59
count 60
useEffect before 59
useEffect after 59

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a stale state. You can verify that by checking out the output from `console.log()` statement inside `setInterval` callback. Even after state is changed to `59`, the interval callback still logs count as `60`. It has closed ([read closures](https://www.google.com/search?q=javsacript+closures+stale+state&oq=javsacript+closures+stale+state&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390.5078j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) over this value and is still printing that.

So first time setInterval callback code runs `setState(59)` is correct to execute and causes a rerender.

Also, React gives a hint as to why sometimes React cannot [bail out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update).  Usually when `setState` is called with same value React does not cause rerender but some times React may still need to rerender, but as mentioned it will not go deeper into the DOM tree.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-rgb-5izydu?file=/src/App.js) that demonstrates the same:

You can see `i am rendered` is not called twice.